the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found (java/angular)
i'm trying to build a project in Angular and Java where i upload a file from the frontend interface to a mysql database through the backend built in spring boot.
When i upload the file from postman it works.
When i upload it from the frontend i get the following error:
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

I'm probably seeting some properties at the frontend in the wrong way,
Here's the angular service's code from where i upload the file:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostFileServiceService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  public postFile(name: string, size: any, type: any): Observable<any>{
    const body = JSON.stringify({name, size, type});
    const Options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'content-type':'multipart/form-data', 'boundary':'----WebKitFormBoundaryG8vpVejPYc8E16By'
  })
}
const url = `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/file/upload?name=${name}&size=${size}&type=${type}`;
return this.http.post(url, body, Options);
 }
}

I've tried to add the multipart boundary options following what was said here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-avoid-no-multipart-boundary-was-found
but i am afraid i spelled it wrong.
Here's the code from the controller class in Java where i manage the calls to the backend:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="api/v1/file")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class filecontroller {
@Autowired
private final FileSystemStorageService filesService;

public filecontroller(FileSystemStorageService filesService) {
    this.filesService = filesService;
}



@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<responseMessage> uploadFiles(@RequestParam MultipartFile file){
    String message = "";
    try{
        filesService.store(file);
        message = "File Uploaded successfully: "+file.getOriginalFilename();
        return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new responseMessage(message));
    }catch (Exception e){
        message = "Could not upload the file: "+file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new responseMessage(message));
    }
}


@GetMapping("/files")
public  ResponseEntity<List<fileResponse>> getListFiles(){
    List<fileResponse> files = filesService.getAllFiles().map(dbFile->{
        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/files/").path(dbFile.getId()).toUriString();
        return new fileResponse(dbFile.getFileName(), dbFile.getFileSize().length, dbFile.getType(), fileDownloadUri);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(files);
}

@GetMapping("/files/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable String id){
    fileToUpload file = filesService.getFile(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\""+file.getFileName()+"\"").body(file.getFileSize());
}



  }

Where am i doing something wrong?
If you need some other code snippet please ask me.
The component HTML:
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
    <p class="pheader">Name</p>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
    <button class="button" (click)="back()">Go back</button>
    <p class="instructions">{{username}}, Upload a file here! </p>
    <button class="ToUser" (click)="toUser()">See all the files uploaded by {{username}}</button>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="uploadContainer">
        <h1 class="center">Upload a file</h1>
        <form>
            <label for="upload" class="upload">
                <span class="span" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <input class="inputFull" id="inputFile" type="file" accept="*" (change)="onChangeFile($event)" #fileUpload>
                <button type="reset" id="resetButton" class='reset'>X</button>
                <button type="button" class="submitButton" (click)="onSubmit()">Upload</button>
            </label>
        </form>
        <div class="uploaded" *ngIf="subscribed==true">
            <p class="filename">File uploaded: {{name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

component js:
constructor(private route: Router, private files:     PostFileServiceService) { }

  public main(){
    this.username = localStorage.getItem('user_name');
   }
  public onChangeFile(event: any){
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    if(this.file){
      this.name = this.file.name;
      this.size = this.file.size;
      this.type = this.file.type;
      this.userName = this.username;
      this.nameOfficial = this.name;
      if(this.nameOfficial.includes(" ")){
        this.nameConcat = this.nameOfficial.split(" ").join("");
      }
     }else if(this.file==null){
       return
     }    
   }
   public onSubmit(){
     this.requestSub = this.files.postFile(this.nameConcat ? this.nameConcat : this.nameOfficial, this.size, this.type).subscribe((resp)=>{
      if(resp==null){
       this.subscribed = true;
       this.toCongrats('fileSuccessfull');
      }
    })
  }
//other methods

Html updated:
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
    <p class="pheader">Name</p>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
    <button class="button" (click)="back()">Go back</button>
    <p class="instructions">{{username}}, Upload a file here! </p>
    <button class="ToUser" (click)="toUser()">See all the files uploaded by {{username}}</button>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="uploadContainer">
        <h1 class="center">Upload a file</h1>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="upload" class="upload">
                <span class="span" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <input class="inputFull" id="inputFile" type="file" accept="*" (change)="onChangeFile($event)" #fileUpload>
                <button type="reset" id="resetButton" class='reset'>X</button>
                <button type="button" class="submitButton" (click)="onSubmit()">Upload</button>
            </label>
        </form>
        <div class="uploaded" *ngIf="subscribed==true">
            <p class="filename">File uploaded: {{name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


If you used an html form, the enctype should be enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in the form tag, there also should be a tag "input" with attribute type="file". and a submit button. That would tell the browser ONLY if the form tag has method="POST" to wrap a special sequence of characters on a newline with some trailing dashes and or equal signs before the attached file bytes that are URL encoded then a newline with the exact reversed character sequence

In a browser scenario, the browser app will create the required headers for the request, but the essence is it is alike a second message body (you can write it all in syntax per text line of the headers and join it all for programmatic construction).   See. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1867

just added the code for the component where the input is located. both frontend and backend, so should i add 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' in the html?

tried adding it to the html and nothing changed, token out the Options from the request service and the error changed to: Current request is not a multipart request

Show the html code fof the form!  Did you specify post or get form method? If it is not post then do not put enctype, it's then simply a get method form and the file is part of the query string parameters. So get the file= the filename then there is a newline CRLF and first boundary character sequence (the other end is reversed boundary characters) parameter "by parameter name" and urlunencode to bytes (URL encoded data is string).

SORRY ----boundary123456 is only post method.  GET is parameters of query string . About this point.  ..... I think you were trying to send to a specific servlet (ws port) using "get" but the required form system is POST method in the ws servlet, requiring proper form tag attributes.

If you are trying to programmatically request from a server to another server with web service port with post request required for the file, use.   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html     set up the headers per line including filename parameter, content length , application/URL encoded ,the blank line then boundary the next line start is URL encoded file bytes value, instantly terminated by reversed boundary sequence and then blank line.

Thank you, no it's a post method, for now :). So i need to add after the enctype that is a post method in the html? How do i do that? Thank you for the reply. I've added the modified html, the last code snippet on my question.

form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://wherever.com/service".     [ the site converted the action URL so it's simply the whole qualified URL to the service port with whatever parameters idiosyncratic ]

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

action="localhost:4200/api/v1/file"     value should have the http colon two // on it (with whatever locator syntax if required)

you mean "http://localhost:8080/" "the rest of the url" like this right? With the double slashes, stackoverflow won't let me add them

instead of constructing it yourself, just use formdata: append the file and the rest, example: how to send a form data to server using post api in angular 7, or: Angular Spring Boot (File+FormData) Upload (probably why it works with postman, and not with your code..)

The html element between the form start and end tag is usually input type="file" id="fileupload" value="".   Note you can put a full path filename in value or leave it zero length in the attribute for the browser user to add or change (they don't tell you but always add the attribute value="" in form input tags). You will need to script a JavaScript test for the user browsers to check a valid file has been added to prevent sending (submit) false. NB don't forget to put a submit button inside the form tags.

Will try traynor, thanks! :)

Will try also this one by Samuel, thanks :)
